# I can't scroll user control for the first time, If not clicking scrollviewer of WPF

Tags: wpf, scroll, scrollviewer

Basically, I can't scroll scrollviewer of WPF for the first time, If not clicking control once.

I tried to use WPF API as Focus(), SetFocus Win32 API, SendMessage and PostMessage as SetCursor after watching windows event with Spy++. But It didn't work.

Only thing I can do scroll is to use mouse_event API to click forcibly.

`[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern void mouse_event(int flags, int dX, int dY, int buttons, int extraInfo);`

Do you have any solution for scrolling???